# fatal: unable to access cannot resolve host gitlab error when using HTTPS git repository

Tags: git, ubuntu, hostname, wsl-2

This is in WSL2 running ubuntu 20.04.

I am trying to use an existing set of code that is on my computer and put it into an empty repository I have on gitlab that is set to HTTPS. It is not set up for SSH and cannot be switched to SSH. All the answer I've seen have been for SSH and have not worked.

This is what I did:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://username@url/repository.git
git config http.sslVerify "false"
git commit -m "message"
git push -u origin master
```

Which gave the error fatal: unable to access [url] could not resolve host [host]

This is what I've tried since:

```
git set-origin https://username@url/repository.git
git set-url origin https://username@url/repository.git
```

All have given the same error after when trying to push again. It hasn't given me prompts to login like it does when doing
`git -c http.sslVerify=false clone https://username@url/repository.git`

Is there anyway to get it to verify this way or do I have to just clone the repository elsewhere and copy everything over?

Thank you!

Comment: To trouble shoot this, try loading the repo URL in your browser in WIndows. Then install lynx in WSL and try to load it there. If lynx fails, try pinging the host to check if there is a route.

Comment: The repo URL works fine in windows but won't open in lynx in WSL or pinging in WSL, but I can ping google. I think the issue might be that my VPN isn't going into WSL because I can ping and lynx google.com.

Comment: Host-name-to-IP-address resolution is normally done by a library routine and/or server process. On normal Linux systems this is the *resolver* library, which is built into libc. Whether WSL substitutes its own, I don't know. A lot of browsers these days have their own resolvers, bypassing the system's, for various reasons, so being able to resolve the name in the browser but not with `ping` points to a libc/libresolv/whatever-they-called-it issue. That could be a configuration issue (`/etc/resolv.conf`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few days later and I have figured out the answer.

In WSL, I didn't have the /etc/resolv.conf set up correctly. Here is the steps I took to set it up.

In windows, `ipconfig.exe /all` take note of all of the DNS servers that WSL needs access to.

Create or edit /etc/wsl.conf to say

```
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
```

Check to see if /etc/resolv.conf is set to immutable `lsattr /etc/resolf.conf` WSL will often have them set to immutable and if it is set to immutable, you won't be able to edit it. To make it no longer immutable type `chattr +i /etc/resolf.conf`.

After that, add all of the DNS IPs from windows into the resolv.conf file like this `namespace 0:0:0:0`. Keep `namespace 8:8:8:8` at the end as a backup in case it fails. 8:8:8:8 is google and allows you to check to see if you have internet at all by using `ping google.com` or if you are completely offline.

For this to go into effect you have to close all WSL windows you have open. Then, in powershell or command prompt you need to type `wsl --shutdown` for your changes to go into effect.